# Inserting into MySQL with Perl

Tags: mysql, database, perl, sql-insert

I have the following bound query in Perl.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("insert into tbl_name values(?,?)");
$sth->execute($val1, $val2);
```

However, what if the first coloumn in that `tbl_name` table is an auto-increment primary key? What do I do to handle that field?

Answer (score 5):

This is more of an SQL problem than a Perl one.

> What do I do to handle [an auto-increment] field?

Don't specify it at all. Explicitly name all the columns you are have values for and ignore the others.

That will cause them to take on their default values which, in the case of an auto-increment field, will be the next increment.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("insert into tbl_name (column_name) values (?)");
$sth->execute($val2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give just the value of the second column, like this

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_name (col2) VALUES (?)');
$sth->execute($val2);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, you just don't specify the value for the field by being explicit on which fields you're inserting, so as they said:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_name (col2) VALUES (?)');
$sth->execute($val2);
```

is going to be good enough.

I just want to add that you can use

```
$dbh->{'mysql_insertid'}
```

to get the id that was assigned to the row, which often comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("insert into tbl_name values(?,?)");
$sth->execute(undef, $val2);
```

or

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("insert into tbl_name (col2_name) values (?)");
$sth->execute($val2);
```